# Apply element hover on an external class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change a button's colour when I hover an external class. This is what I made but it doesn't work..

HTML:

```
<table class="hover_element">
    Hover me!
</table>
<div class="first_div">
    <div class="second_div">
        <div class="third_div">
            <button class="apply_hover">
                Apply hover on this element
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hover_element:hover ~ .first_div .second_div .third_div .apply_hover {
    color: orange;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/2754/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed my whole answer after your edit.

The problem here is that you should remove the `:hover` from `.hover_element` class:

```
.hover_element ~  .first_div .second_div .third_div .apply_hover:hover
```

**Working jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/2758/

If you wanted that the `hover` event of the table highlighted the div under it, two things should be done:

1.to add `<tr><td>` to the table (the `:hover` event won't work otherwise):

```
<table class="hover_element">
    <tr>
        <td>Hover me!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

2.to remove the `:hover` from `.apply_hover`:

```
.hover_element:hover ~ .first_div .second_div .third_div .apply_hover
```

**Working jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/2759/

if you want to highlight both of them at the same time (on the `:hover` event of `.hover_element`), then this should be added:

```
.hover_element:hover, .hover_element:hover ~ .first_div .second_div .third_div .apply_hover
```

**Working jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/umz8t/2760/

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong css code in jsfiddle. I don't want to use another class for this